# Making ValueListener only happen once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering if it is possible to make the code in a value event listener only happen one time.

I have a value listener that checks whether or not the 2 players in the game have clicked the `ready` button. If they have, then the code in the listener will happen which is good, but I only want it to happen once.

The issue is since the conditions in the listener are true, the code executes over and over and over. This is a simplified version of the listener

```
   games.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID.child("ready").getValue().equals(true)) {
                        runCounter();
                        Log.i("FlipCoin", "``ButtonClickListener happened");
                    }
                }
            });
```

SO once the conditions in the if statement are true, the code within the if statement fires over and over. I know this is happening because I put a log statement in the statement and it continues to print in the log.

How can I go about making it so that this code only fires one time, until prompted to fire again? I know one method would be setting the condition in the if statement to `false` right after the code happens, but that poses issues as I need the value to read true for other methods in my code to work

Comment: Maybe remove the listener after it's executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove it after it's invoked:

```
games.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID.child("ready").getValue().equals(true))) {
                runCounter();
                    Log.i("FlipCoin", "``ButtonClickListener happened");
                }
            }
        });

        games.removeEventListener(this); //remove it here
    }
});
```

If you need to reuse this listener, assign it to a variable:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    //contents from above
}
```

Then just use:

```
games.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

whenever you want it to work.

Comment: Is there a way to reactivate the listener again later in the code? I have 4 or 5 instances of `games.addValueEventListener` so how would I reactivate this specific block of code when need be?